# Double Condition

Tags: javascript

It will make selection words starting with "p" and ending with "a". Why it didnt work?

```
function checkWord(word) {
    if (word.charAt(0) = 'p' && word.charAt(word.length - 1) = 'a') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

Comment: you should check condition with ==

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison

Comment: Look at your console. It will show the message `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. Also, avoid the `if (b) return true; else return false;` anti-pattern, You can just say `return b;`.

Comment: Or, run your code through a linter, such as the one at http://eslint.org/demo/, which will tell you `Parsing error: Assigning to rvalue`.

Comment: Any good tutorial will walk you through things like the difference between `=` and `==` or `===`. Here's [one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/JavaScript_basics#Operators).

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used for assigning values, not checking them. Use `==` for checking the values and `===` for checking value and types. So, your code should be like:

```
function checkWord(word) {
    if (word.charAt(0) === 'p' && word.charAt(word.length - 1) === 'a') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put 2 equals to if you only put 1 equals you are assigning it and if you put 2 equals you're comparing it the. below code should help

```js
 /* Check weather the first letter is equals to p and the last letter is equals to a. */
 function checkWord(word) {
        let firstPAndLastA = false;
        if(word != null){
            if (word.charAt(0) == 'p' && word.charAt(word.length - 1) == 'a') {
              firstPAndLastA = true;
            } else {
              firstPAndLastA = false;
            }
        }
        return firstPAndLastA;
    }

 //Calling Function
 console.log(checkWord("ppoa"))
```